# How to save money while protecting it from inflation for a home?

Tags: stocks, real-estate, stock-markets, savings, inflation

Last time I heard from my friend that M1 money supply year increase in my country is about 35% and economy is frozen (I don't known is it true, but let assume that it is true in some country X).

If I understood correctly it means that people have a lot of money on their bank accounts or cash and they don't spend their money now and their amount of money is growing as they all get paid from their employees and their employees get money from government help (because of COVID pandemic), so generally money are printed in huge amount.

Also my friend said that when this COVID pandemic will finish we are expecting huge increase in real estate prices and worthless money, because people will start spending their money which they are gathering now.

I have two questions:

1. **What is the probability that this scenario will happen?** Not only in country X, but in any country in Europe Union or North America during pandemic?
2. **How to save my money from inflation?** I don't have enough money to buy a flat now (I'm renting  and saving for my own), a mortgage is not an option for me now, so I'm thinking about buying a shares of some companies (especially energy market), but if price of homes go up, is it probable that stock market also go up in general?

Sorry, for my English feel free to edit :)

Comment: Your question #1 is broad, opinion based, and not really suited for this stack. I would say Economics.Stack might be a better place for it, but you would need to narrow it down to a specific country and probably also rephrase like "What makes this more or less likely today in this country?". Your question #2 is not really asking about "inflation" per se, it is more asking about real estate values. Inflation can be stagnant and yet home prices can still shoot up 30% in 5 years as it has done in some markets recently. So that means your question #1 & #2 aren't really related and can be separate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don’t be too concerned. Inflation is a function of both the money supply and the velocity of money, and of course the velocity of money has slowed down a lot during the pandemic and so the money supply has had to be increased in order to compensate for that and avoid serious deflation. In most cases, it’s been done in ways that can be reversed as the monetary velocity returns to normal.

Having said that, if your country offers index-linked government bonds in your currency, they’re pretty much a 100% guaranteed hedge against inflation, though they may have negative yields at present. Otherwise, equities with a steady yield such as the utilities that you mention are pretty good.

Comment: Unless there's an equity bubble...